# Insert special char like ♦☺♦♣◘• into SQL Server database

Tags: .net, sql-server

From any input filled I want to pass special chars like ♦☺♦♣◘• into a SQL Server database, if `Notes` input parameter is like " ♦☺♦♣◘•"

Then when I click on edit I need to get in "♦☺♦♣◘•" in `Notes` filled and in database it also need to insert into `Notes` column value " ♦☺♦♣◘•".`

```
SqlParameter[] param = 
{
    new SqlParameter("@ManagerComment", seqm.Notes), 
    new SqlParameter("@GroupId", groupId)
};
```

Comment: What is the exact problem? Are there errors? Please also always include enough code to show the problem. Now there’s just two parameters without any SQL statements or code to run it.

Answer (score 1):

1. You should define the datatype in the backend table as `NVARCHAR` datatype. I am showing a sample `INSERT` for the `NVARCHAR` column:

```sql
CREATE TABLE #Test(Notes NVARCHAR(255)) 

INSERT INTO #Test 
VALUES (N'♦☺♦♣◘•')

SELECT * FROM #Test
```

2. When you are passing values to stored procedure for insertion, you have to pass the parameter value as `NVARCHAR`. I am showing sample `SqlParameter` to pass for notes.

```cs
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.Insertstoredprocedure", connection);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ManagerComment", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 255);
cmd.Parameters["@ManagerComment"].Value = " ♦☺♦♣◘•";
```